# Django forms templates escape

Tags: python, django

```
{% if form.subject.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```

I have taken the above code from a template, a form is passed in under the key 'form'
However, i have never encountered |escape before?
Is | the or bitwise operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is the [**`|escape`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escape). As is specified by the documentation:

> Escapes a string’s HTML. Specifically, it makes these replacements:
>
> 1. `<` is converted to `&lt;`
> 2. `>` is converted to `&gt;`
> 3. `'` (single quote) is converted to `&#x27;`
> 4. `"` (double quote) is converted to `&quot;`
> 5. `&` is converted to `&amp;`
>
> Applying escape to a variable that would normally have auto-escaping
>   applied to the result will only result in one round of escaping being
>   done. So it is safe to use this function even in auto-escaping
>   environments. If you want multiple escaping passes to be applied, use
>   the `force_escape` filter.

It is likely in a [**`{% autoscape off %}…{% endautoescape %}`** block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape), since by default Django already escapes the items. It will thus make sure that if the variable is a string that contains characters that can be interpreted as html, these are escaped to prevent that.